# Deserialize json field from a complex object in scala

Tags: json, scala, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am working in Scala programming language

My formatted json payload is

```
{
   "took":1,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":25,
      "successful":25,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":0.72271335,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"machinename_guid",
            "_type":"type",
            "_id":"id",
            "_score":0.72271335,
            "_source":{
               "Name":"NAME",
               "Data":{
                  "Name":"NAME"
                  "Ver":"VERSION",
                  "$type":"lib, ServiceTest",
                  "ProductName":"PRODUCTNAME",
                  "Id":"ID"
                  "Data":"DATA TOBE RETRIVED"
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to de-serialize the following section to class

```
 "Data":{
    "Name":"NAME"
    "Ver":"VERSION",
    "$type":"lib, ServiceTest",
    "ProductName":"PRODUCTNAME",
    "Id":"ID"
    "Data":"DATA TOBE RETRIVED"
 }
```

What would be the easiest way to achieve this in scala?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the easiest option would be to de-serialize complete Json response to class and extract the desired data from that class.

```
case class Data(name: String,ver: String,type: String,productName: String,id: String,data: String)
case class Foo(name: String,data: Data)
case class Result(_source: Foo, _score: Float, _index: String, _type: String, _id: String)
case class HitsResult(hits: List[Result], total: Int)
case class Response(hits: HitsResult)
```

Now, you can de-serialize your Json response to above `Response` case class using any JSON library and you can easily extract your desired data i.e. Foo from the response.